# Hide/Expand-type container in Java

Tags: java, swing

I need an expand/hideable component such as show in IntellijIdea's "Edit Configuration" menu:
[image]

When clicking on a triangle to the left of "Before launch", it expands/hides the activities therein. I tried this: https://github.com/oliverwatkins/swing_library/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gg/slider/SliderTester.java
Somehow, *my speculation* is that it expects some sort of a list, since when I tried to put a `JPanel` with my custom activities, it somehow failed to show. Do you think `JetBrains` built this thing in a custom way, or is this actually easy? I tried to follow Occam's Razor and not to reinvent the wheel, so I searched around, and posting here since it didn't work for me.

Comment: have you tried Accordion for Swing? Please take look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944256/accordion-for-swing

Comment: Yes, the GitHub link above is from that answer.